# TypeError: Rich Embed is not a constructor on my poll command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so I was coding a poll bot and I was making something to where if a user says only 'poll' the system would respond with an embed, however, I received an error when I did the command saying: `TypeError: RichEmbed is not a constructor`. My code is shown below:

```
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch(args[0]){

        case "poll":
            const Embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0xFFC300)
            .setTitle("Initiate Poll")
            .setDescription("p!poll to initiate a simple yes or no poll!");

            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send(Embed);
            }
        break;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `RichEmbed` has a constructor? See more information at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor

Answer (score 0):

It [says here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#richembed-constructor) that

> The `RichEmbed` constructor has been removed and now the `MessageEmbed` constructor is used. It is largely the same to use, the only differences being the removal of `richEmbed.attachFile` (`messageEmbed.attachFiles` accepts a single file as a parameter as well) and `richEmbed.addBlankField` and the addition of `messageEmbed.addFields`.

Answer (score 0):

Since discord.js v12 you need to use [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) instead of `RichEmbed`